# Program for learning french

Tags: vocabulaire, apprentissage, travail

I am looking for an online site/program where I could refresh my french especially the french related to the hotel reception...

Do you maybe know such a site/program?

Answer (score 2):

Here you can do exercises to understand french language in an hotel situation :

[www.bonjourdefrance.com](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/le-francais-du-tourisme.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Babbel](https://fr.babbel.com/) (website and app) can also help you.

[Babbel](https://fr.babbel.com/) (site web et application) peut aussi t'aider.

Answer (score 1):

Duolingo is a pretty good site to learn a new language (not only french).
https://www.duolingo.com/

There is a mobile app too, so you can practise everywhere.

It is not specialized for hotel trade though.